# is it possible remove for loops from my code?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

i want to remove nested for loops from my code?
i can't remove them.

```
k = 3;    
Data = rand(100,5);    
m = zeros(size(Data));    
N = size(Data,2); % number of features
M = size(Data,1); % number of objects
bound = zeros(N,k+1);

MAX = max(Data);
MIN = min(Data);


for ii = 1:N
    bound(ii,:) = linspace(MIN(ii), MAX(ii), k+1);
end

bound(:,end) = bound(:,end)+eps;

tic;
for ii = 1:M
    for jj=1:N
        for kk=1:k
            if bound(jj,kk)<=Data(ii,jj) && Data(ii,jj)<bound(jj,kk+1)
                m(ii,jj) = kk;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with nesting upto a certain limit.

At a glance, as the `jj` index seems to be uniform in the operation within the nested loop, you can replace

```
for ii = 1:M
    for jj=1:N
        for kk=1:k
            if bound(jj,kk)<=Data(ii,jj) && Data(ii,jj)<bound(jj,kk+1)
                m(ii,jj) = kk;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

by simply

```
for ii = 1:M
    for kk=1:k
        m(ii,(bound(:,kk)<=Data(ii,:)' & Data(ii,:)'<bound(:,kk+1))) = kk;
    end
end
```

This would give you the exact same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Since your longest loop is over `ii=1:M`, we should prioritise vectorising this one over the others. The smallest loop is over `kk=1:k` so this one can probably stay without worrying about it too much. You can use `bsxfun` to great effect in vectorisations of this sort:

```
for kk = 1:k
    ind = bsxfun(@le, bound(:, kk)', Data) & bsxfun(@gt, bound(:, kk+1)', Data);
    m(ind) = kk;
end
```

This gives the same result as your above code.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is `histc()`, which is specifically designed for binning:

```
for jj = 1:N
   [~, m(:,jj)] =  histc(Data(:,jj),bound(jj,:));
end
```

This solution is on par with `bsxfun()` but it's not a very meaningful comparison because here the loop is across columns while with bsxfun is across bounds. Therefore, as a rule of thumb I would go with `histc()` if I have less columns than bounds, otherwise `bsxfun()`.